# Structure Database Firestore Posts

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Real Time x Firestore database structure

System structure posts in Real Time:

```
Posts
--ID_USER_1
----IdPost1
------Date
------Image
---IdPost2
------Date
------Image
---IdPost3
------Date
------Image
--ID_USER_2
----IdPost1
------Date
------Image
---IdPost2
------Date
------Image
---IdPost3
------Date
------Image
```

Post system model in RealTime. To structure in the Firestore, it could look something like this:

```
Post
--ID_POST1
----Id_user1
----Image
--ID_POST2
----Id_user2
----Image
```

From what I understand in Firestore has the constraints of collections, because when converting to the same structure of Real Time, it would not work because we can not have two collections like: **mDB.collection ("Posts").collection().**

What is the best way to structure a posting system between users?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that in Cloud Firestore you have to alternate between documents and collections, but I don't believe that will be a problem for your data structure.

For instance you could have:

```
  - `posts` [collection]
    - `ID_USER_1` [document]
      - `posts` [subcollection]
         - `ID_POST_1` [document]
           - `Date` [field]
           - `Image` [field]
         - `ID_POST_2` [document]
           - `Date` [field]
           - `Image` [field]
```

So to get all the posts for a user you could do:

```
db.collection('posts').doc('user1234').collection('posts').get()

// OR

db.collection('posts/user1234/posts').get()
```

Since Cloud Firestore also has fast and powerful queries, you could also store all of your posts in one top-level `posts` collection and store `UserId` as a property of the post:

```
  - `posts` [collection]
     - `ID_POST_1` [document]
       - `UserId` [field]
       - `Date` [field]
       - `Image` [field]
     - `ID_POST_2` [document]
       - `UserId` [field]
       - `Date` [field]
       - `Image` [field]
```

And then to get all of the posts for a user you could do:

```
db.collection('posts').where('UserId', '==', 'user1234')
```

Comment: I am curious how I would handle this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347695/how-to-structure-firestore-database-for-following-social-media-use